# What is the difference between placing wheel chocks on the outer wheels as opposed to the inner wheels of the main landing gear?

Tags: airline-operations, iata

Recently I am aware of a change made to the IATA Ground Operations Manual (IGOM) in regards to the position of the wheel chock on the main landing gear.

[image: Inner][image]

Is there a justification for why one method is preferred or is safer than the other?

Comment: Just a guess: Easier to see and therefore harder to forget if they are on the outer wheels.

Comment: Or perhaps, the ground crew doesn't have to walk in front of or behind un-chocked wheels before inserting or after removing the chocks? Typically more headroom outboard of the gear compared with inboard? Better visibility to know that they are installed? Any or all of the above?

Comment: I note that the comments are based on the assumption that the new rules indicate chocking the outer wheel. Can you confirm that's the rule now

Comment: In the 4th edition (2015) the outer wheels were chocked, and from the [list of changes](http://www.iata.org/publications/store/Documents/ahm38-igom07-changes-merged-20171106.pdf?utm_source=AirportBusiness&utm_campaign=AHM18&utm_term=airport_handling), it seems it changed in 7th ed. (2017).

Answer (score 1):

If the inner wheels are chocked, the ground crew person would likely have to place their arm/hand in the path of the wheels to grab the rope and pick up the chock.